React js routing for Link for navbar log tag is not working
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import './index.css'
import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import Layout from './Layout.jsx'
import Log from './components/log.jsx';
const mainRoutes = [
  {
    path: '/', 
    element: <Layout />,
    children: [
      {
        path:'log',
        element:<Log/>,
      }
      
    ],
  },
];


const router = createBrowserRouter(mainRoutes);
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
  <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>,
)


this is my code where I have implemented routing .
In layout I have header and
<>
  <Header/> 
  <Home/>
</>

inside header file I try to route like this
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
<Link to='/log' className="nav-link text-white" >Log</Link>

The routing is not working as expected I have already tried to check if the issue is in layout.

In the Parent (Layout) you have to mention where to render the child routes using the Outlet component.
 <>
   <Header/> 
   <Home/>
   <Outlet />
 </>

In this example, when /log is called, the component tree would be
Header
Home
Log


yes i dont know that we have to use for inherit thing Outlet

sorry, I didn't quite get you, are you saying your issue got fixed? If not please provide a codesandbox link

my issue solved
